# rails 4 with nested attributes and nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to model my first rails 4 project to make the leap from tutorial to the real world.

The app is a horse show signup.

- The user (devise) adds an 'entry'.
- The entry can consists one or more 'rides'
- Each ride can have a single 'horse' and a single 'rider' (nested forms would allow user to select existing horse and rider or create new one via form during new entry create.

I started to do some nested web forms with Cocoon and Formtastic:
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

buy I have problems with saving related data to tables.

When I save my entry the rides table contains correct values for:
test, entry_id, but not horse_id

The entry table has no ride_id value.  It only has user_id (I set in controller manually)

My questions are:
I am sure I am missing a few conceptual concepts but do I have my models associations set up correctly?
How do I edit my current forms to save data correctly?

When I debug in the controller I get what looks to be an odd param value:

{"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=", "entry"=>{"show_date"=>"10/26/2014", "rides_attributes"=>{"1407930343404"=>{"test"=>"Intro B", "horses"=>{"name"=>"Plain Horse", "_destroy"=>""}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Entry", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"entries"}

I thought I would see 'horses_attributes' within the 'rides_attributes' hash but instead I see just 'horses'.

Any clarification including link to examples would be very appeciated.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :entries 
  has_many :rides, :through => :entries 
  has_many :horses,  :through => :entries   
  has_many :riders, :through => :entries
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :rides, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :horses, :through => :rides
  has_many :riders, :through => :rides

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :rides, :allow_destroy => true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :horses 
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :riders
end

class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :horse #, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :rider

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :horse
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rider
end

class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ride # :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Rider < ActiveRecord::Base
    #belongs_to :ride #,  :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :rides
end
```

Here is my partial schema:

```
create_table "entries", force: true do |t|
  t.date     "show_date"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "ride_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "entries", ["ride_id"], name: "index_entries_on_ride_id", using: :btree
add_index "entries", ["user_id"], name: "index_entries_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "horses", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "horse_ncdcta"
  t.string   "owner_fname"
  t.string   "owner_lname"
  t.date     "coggins_date"
  t.integer  "ride_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "horses", ["ride_id"], name: "index_horses_on_ride_id", using: :btree

create_table "riders", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "first_name"
 t.string   "last_name"
 t.string   "rider_ncdcta"
 t.boolean  "senior"
 t.boolean  "liability_signed"
 t.integer  "ride_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "riders", ["ride_id"], name: "index_riders_on_ride_id", using: :btree

create_table "rides", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "test"
 t.integer  "entry_id"
 t.integer  "rider_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.integer  "horse_id"
end

add_index "rides", ["entry_id"], name: "index_rides_on_entry_id", using: :btree
add_index "rides", ["rider_id"], name: "index_rides_on_rider_id", using: :btree

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "phone"
end
```

partial entry controller:

```
def new
  @user=current_user
  @entry=Entry.new
end

def create
  @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
  @entry.user_id=current_user[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.save  
      # example of params value
      # {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=", "entry"=>{"show_date"=>"10/26/2014", "rides_attributes"=>{"1407930343404"=>{"test"=>"Intro B", "horses"=>{"name"=>"Plain Horse", "_destroy"=>""}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Entry", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"entries"}
      debugger
      format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def entry_params
  # added ids based on comments below
  params.require(:entry).permit(:show_date, rides_attributes: [:id, :test,  :_destroy, horses_attributes: [:name, :id]] ) 
end
```

views:
_form.html.haml

```
= semantic_form_for @entry do |f|
  = f.inputs do
  = f.label :show_date, "Show Date"
  = f.input :show_date, :as => :select, :collection => [['08/03/2014', '08/03/2014'], ['09/14/2014', '09/14/2014'], ['10/26/2014', '10/26/2014'], ['11/15/2014', '11/15/2014']]

  %h3 Rides
  #rides
    = f.semantic_fields_for :rides do |ride|
      = render 'ride_fields', :f => ride

    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add ride', f, :rides

  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit
```

_ride_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  = f.inputs do
  = f.label :test, "Test"
  = f.input :test, :as => :select, :collection => [['Intro A', 'Intro A'], ['Intro B', 'Intro B'], ['Intro C', 'Intro C']]

  = f.semantic_fields_for :horses do |horse|
    = render 'horse_fields', :f => horse

    = link_to_add_association 'add horse', f, :horse
```

_horse_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  =f.inputs do
  = f.input :name
.links
  = link_to_add_association 'add horse', f, :horse
```

Comment: can you show the parameters whitelisting methods? like entry_params..

Comment: I have tried a few variations including horses instead of horses_attributes.  params.require(:entry).permit(:show_date, rides_attributes: [:test,  :_destroy, horses_attributes: [:name]] )

Comment: you have always pass :id of every nested resource

Comment: I added ids:  params.require(:entry).permit(:show_date, rides_attributes: [:id, :test,  :_destroy, horses_attributes: [:name, :id]] )  but I still do not get key _ids set in tables.  :show_date is not set in entry table etc.  My params looks like this now: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=", "entry"=>{"show_date"=>"11/15/2014", "rides_attributes"=>{"1408016228347"=>{"test"=>"Intro C", "horses"=>{"name"=>"Testy2", "_destroy"=>""}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Entry", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"entries"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now saving relationships correctly with below code (with a one caveat).  Thanks to previous posters for getting me headed in the right direction!

Also Formtastic doc link:  http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput

The caveat: I cannot figure out how to select an existing horse with form select if I do not want to add a new horse (_ride_fields.html.haml).  Adding new horse works fine.
When I attempt with current commented code I get error:
undefined method ride_id for Ride
I am not sure if this a formtastic problem, model related, or controller.  I will post this as a separate question if I do not figure it out.

I realized in my original posting that I should not have foreign keys (eg ride_id) saved to 'entries' table because they are saved to the related tables (rides) in entry_id field.

entries controller (partial):

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :set_horses, :except => [:destroy, :index]

def new
  @c_user=current_user[:id]
  @user=current_user
  @entry = current_user.entries.new
  @horses = current_user.horses
end

def create

  @entry = current_user.entries.new(entry_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.save  
      format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

def set_horses
 if current_user.admin?
   @horses=Horse.all
 else
   @horses = current_user.horses 
 end 
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:show_date, rides_attributes: [:id, :test,  :_destroy, horse_attributes: [:name, :id]] ) 
  end
end
```

entry.rb:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rides, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :horses, :through => :rides, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :riders, :through => :rides, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rides, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:test].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :horses, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :riders, :allow_destroy => true

  validates_presence_of :show_date
end
```

ride.rb:

```
class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry, inverse_of: :entry
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user
  has_one :horse 
  has_one :rider

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :horse
end
```

horse.rb:

```
class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ride, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

_form.html.haml

```
= semantic_form_for @entry do |f|
  = f.inputs do
  = f.input :show_date, :as => :select, :collection => ['2014/08/03', '2014/09/14', '2014/10/26', '2014/11/15']
  %h3 Rides
  #rides
    = f.semantic_fields_for :rides do |ride|
      = render 'ride_fields', :f => ride 
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add ride', f, :rides

  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit
```

_ride_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  = f.inputs do
    = f.label :test, "Test"
   = f.input :test, :as => :select, :collection => [['Intro A', 'Intro A'], ['Intro B', 'Intro B'], ['Intro C', 'Intro C']]

    = if !@horses.empty?
      -# both of next 2 lines give error: undefined method ride_id for <Ride:0x00000008cc3370>  
      -#= f.input :horse, :as => :select, :collection => @horses
      -#= f.input :horse, :as => :select, :member_label => :name

    = f.semantic_fields_for :horse do |horse|
      = render 'horse_fields', :f => horse

  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'add new horse', f, :horse
```

_horse_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is happening, you're nesting horse within Rides instead of Entry.  Ride accepts nested attributes for a has_one horse relationship so you're seeing 'horses'.  If you submitted horses against the Entry (which has a has_many relationship) you'd see horses_attributes.

In this section of  _form.html.haml you assigned `ride` to `f`

```
 = render 'ride_fields', :f => ride
```

And then in your _ride_fields.html.haml you use that `f` to create a nested form which is being created off the `ride` variable (Ride has_one horse).

```
 = f.semantic_fields_for :horses do |horse|
   = render 'horse_fields', :f => horse
```

Because your `Ride` model has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :horse` you're seeing `horses` within the Ride. To see `horses_attributes` you'll want to create horses against the Entry (which accepts the nested attributes for "horses").

I believe you can fix it by changing the `render` like this (pass in the Entry model form):

```
= render 'ride_fields', :f => ride, :e => f
```

And then the horse nested form like this (from `f` to `e`):

```
 = e.semantic_fields_for :horses do |horse|
   = render 'horse_fields', :f => horse
```

Comment: This gives me error: undefined local variable or method `e'  for the line: = e.semantic_fields_for :horses do |horse| in _ride_fields.html.haml

Comment: If I comment out the line: = link_to_add_association 'add ride', f, :rides in _form.html.haml then I loose the ability to add a ride but I do not get error in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

When using nested attributes the symbol you pass to `form_for` has to match the association name. You are doing

```
f.semantic_fields_for :horses
```

But rides doesn't have a horses assocation, only a horse association. Because of this rails doesn't realise that you're trying to use nested attributes at all, which is why the data is nested under the key "horses" rather than "horses_attributes". You will of course need to change the permitted params to match.

In addition you don't need all the stuff to manage adding extra horse fields for a ride if a ride can in fact only have one horse. If this was a mistake, then leave your forms alone but change the model so that a ride `has_many :horses` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :horses`

Comment: I changed line to  = f.semantic_fields_for :horse do |horse| in the _ride_fields.html.haml but I still need to actually select and/or add a horse.  That option goes away when I change horses to singular. I want the user to select existing horses related to them or add a new one if they need it without having to go to a separate form.  I had stated in ride model has_many :horses but I changed because there is only 1 given horse possible for a particular ride.